# TypeScript error TS 2339 'property ___ does not exist on type never' when iterating using map and find

Tags: typescript

I am getting this error when I attempt to iterate over arrays of objects in order to match them and then do some key reassignment.

[image]

The source code I'm having an issue with is [here](https://github.com/alexmkio/can-i/blob/refactor/typescript/src/utils/cleanData.ts#L33-L39).
I tried to reproduce it in a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/never-type-d3ooj?file=/src/cleanData.ts) but couldn't. Wondering if this means it has something to do with how the array of objects are *actually* created using reduce and push [here](https://github.com/alexmkio/can-i/blob/refactor/typescript/src/utils/cleanData.ts#L5-L7).

I attempted solution by only running the iterators if each array had length, but no luck [there](https://github.com/alexmkio/can-i/blob/refactor/typescript/src/utils/cleanData.ts#L9-L10) either.

Any help would be much appreciated! I am new to TypeScript and eager to learn!

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to provide an explicit type for `currentWindowObject`

`.find( (currentWindowObject: ICurrentWindowObject) => { ... });`